# Pass Java 8 streaming map function as a parameter

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have a string which is comma separated an I want to convert it to an array. However in some cases, I require integer parsing, sometimes double.
Is there a way I can pass mapToDouble or mapToInt rather than writing the entire thing again.

```
return Arrays.stream(test.split(",")).mapToDouble(x -> {
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(x)) {
            return condition ? -1 : 0;
        }
        return Double.parseDouble(x);
}).toArray();

return Arrays.stream(test.split(",")).mapToInt(x -> {
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(x)) {
            return condition ? -1 : 0;
        }
        return Integer.parseInt(x);
}).toArray();
```

Is there a way to make this into a function, where I can have a generic function and make store the appropriate array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with a simple function that accepts `String` and a `Function<String, T>` that will convert every string element using this function. The good news is that this function may return any type you want: `Integer`, `Double`, `BigDecimal`, `String` or any other type you want. In below example I use a method reference like:

- `Integer::valueOf` to convert elements to `Integer` values
- `Double::valueOf` to convert elements to `Double` values
- `String::valueOf` to convert elements to `String` values

Consider following example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ParsingStringTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "1, , 3, 4, 5, , 7, sasd, aaa, 0";

        List<Double> doubles = parse(str, Double::valueOf);
        List<Integer> integers = parse(str, Integer::valueOf);
        List<String> strings = parse(str, String::valueOf);

        System.out.println(doubles);
        System.out.println(integers);
        System.out.println(strings);

        Double[] array = doubles.toArray(new Double[doubles.size()]);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }

    public static <T> List<T> parse(String str, Function<String, T> parseFunction) {
        return Arrays.stream(str.split(","))
                .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
                .map(s -> {
                    try {
                        return parseFunction.apply(s.trim());
                    } catch (Exception e) {}
                    return null;
                })
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Console output for following example is:

```
[1.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 7.0, 0.0]
[1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 0]
[1, , 3, 4, 5, , 7, sasd, aaa, 0]
[1.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 7.0, 0.0]
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Could you paste whole stacktrace? What Java version you use? I've tested it with OpenJDK 1.8.0_141, here is the video of my IDE: https://youtu.be/OXA3rC15JBg

Comment: I got rid of that error. I am calling it this way:
Double[] result = parse(str, Double::valueOf);

I get an error: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Double;

Comment: This is because `.toArray()` returns `Object[]` and arrays cannot be cast to other class that simply. If you want to keep solution simple I would recommend returning `List<T>` instead of `T[]` because you can always simply convert list to any array when you know the size and type of input list. That's why Federico used `.toArray(T[])` method, but in this case you have to provide array generator function. Pick what is best for you, both answers are good imho.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that. Also in my original Post, I replace blank with 1 & 0. Is it possible to make it 1.0 in the case of using Double? Like making it a generic one again?

Comment: @user1692342 Yes, you can always provide a custom function that modifies input, e.g. https://gist.github.com/wololock/06232e6ea20036b217a6b9e7ff411a55

Answer (score 3):

There is a way, but you wouldn't be working with primitives any more, because generics in Java doesn't support primitive types. Instead, you can use `Integer` and `Double` wrapper types:

```
public static <T> T[] convert(
        String test, 
        Function<String, T> parser,
        boolean condition, 
        T ifConditionTrue,
        T ifConditionFalse,
        IntFunction<T[]> arrayGenerator) {

    return Arrays.stream(test.split(","))
        .map(x -> {
            if (StringUtils.isEmpty(x)) {
                return condition ? ifConditionTrue : ifConditionFalse;
            }
            return parser.apply(x);
        })
        .toArray(arrayGenerator);
}
```

This method can be used as follows:

```
Integer[] ints = convert("1, ,3", Integer::parseInt, true, -1, 0, Integer[]::new);
```